# Java : list that contains unique elements in order

Tags: java, list, collections

Is there a list type in java that stores objects in ascending order and not adds if this object is previously added. I know java maps can do that but I wonder if there is a list type that does what I want. Otherwise I have to override contains, equalsTo and add methods,right?

Comment: What order do you mean  - by insertion or natural order?

Comment: Then derive the `ArrayList` and override `add` methods.Test the object existence using `contains` method before adding object into it. Order means access by index(like list) right?

Comment: No, you shouldn't override contains, since contains depends on the equals() of the content type. What you should override is the equals method of your type you wish to store in the collection. (And hashcode if you use hashed collections). The best choice is TreeSet, anyway, as it was already mentioned. (Or LinkedHashSet, if you need to keep the instertion order rather than some kind of a natural order)

Comment: @Prince John Wesley: overriding ArrayList is not a good idea since lists are semantically not about uniqueness. Apart from that, there are better solutions than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I am sorry that I forgot to tell more about order. I want to store my objects in ascending order. thank you by the way for your responses.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

So you need a list containing only unique elements? Two options:

- `java.util.LinkedHashSet` - preserves the order of insertion, has the set semantics
- from commons-collections [`SetUniqueList`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/list/SetUniqueList.html) - allows list operations like `get(..)` and `set(..)`
- from commons-collections [`ListOrderedSet`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/set/ListOrderedSet.html)

Comment: +1 For not totally ignoring asker's requirements and saying he needs an (arbitrary) Set.

Comment: yeah, his requirement was "preserve the order", which a `LinkedHashSet` does. And if he needs random access, he can use one of the other options

Answer (score 18):

Depends on what order do you mean.

- Sorting order - use [`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)
- Order of insertion - use [`LinkedHashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

Comment: tried LinkedHashSet, it does not provide the way to get the index of an element. What is the use of having an ordered set if you can't find the order?

Answer (score 4):

TreeSet will do the trick. Example :

`SortedSet<Integer> myOrderedUniqueList = new TreeSet<Integer>()`

Answer (score 4):

I think you're after a SortedSet (this is an interface which extends Set). Set is like a List but it contains only one of each value.

TreeSet is a commonly-used implementation of SortedSet

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Answer (score 1):

[TreeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) might be exactly what you need.

It stores the elements in a sorted tree. So you can iterate over them in sorted order.
It's not a list, but it performs better with respect to add and contains.

Answer (score 1):

SortedSet is a subinterface of Set, which guarantees that the elements in the set are sorted.

```
SortedSet<Integer> orderedSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
```

Use them when you have to stores non-duplicate elements in increasing order of the element values

Answer (score 0):

It is not a list, but you can look at implementations of Set http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.LinkedHashSet with overridden hashCode() and equals(Object obj) using the unique property(s)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> List<T> getUniqueListOrdered(List<T> values) {
    Set<T> uniqueValues = new HashSet<>();
    return values.stream().filter(value -> uniqueValues.add(value)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}


@Test
public void createUnique() {
    List<String> unique = ListUtils.getUniqueListOrdered(Arrays.asList("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"));
    Assert.assertEquals(unique, Arrays.asList("A", "B"));
}
```

Comment: this is java8 impl